# Duplicate data google apps script and javascript on upload files

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I have a web app with GAS that create folders, upload files, set permissions and save the registers on a sheet.
Ocassionally the app duplicate files when the functions finished and duplicate a register in the google sheet. I don't know how to avoid this error, and the console does not show the error either.
What could be happening? How can I prevent this problem?

This is my code for server side functions:

```
function fileExists(idfileexist,folderId) {

var consulta = DriveApp.getFileById(idfileexist).getName()

  var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName(consulta);
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var folders = file.getParents();
    if (folders.hasNext()) {
      var folder = folders.next();
      if (folder.getId() == folderId) {
        
        return true;
        
      }
    }
  }
  
  return false;
}

function removepermission(id, user){
DriveApp.getFileById(id).removeEditor(user)
}
function appendrow(idfile,sheet,numsip,rut,timestamp,user,idfolder,input,ticket){

var values = SpreadsheetApp.openById(idfile);
var ss= values.getSheetByName(sheet);
ss.appendRow([numsip,rut,timestamp,user,idfolder,input,ticket])

}

function setpermisoswriter(id,array){

var file = DriveApp.getFileById(id)
var editors = file.getEditors();
if (editors.length > 0) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    Drive.Permissions.insert({'role': 'writer','type': 'user','value': array[i]},id,{'sendNotificationEmails': 'false' });};};
}
function setpermisosreader(id,array){
var file = DriveApp.getFileById(id)
var editors = file.getEditors();
if (editors.length > 0) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    Drive.Permissions.insert({'role': 'reader','type': 'user','value': array[i]},id,{'sendNotificationEmails': 'false' });};};
}
function setownerid(id,user){
Drive.Permissions.insert({'role': 'owner','type': 'user','value': user},id,{'sendNotificationEmails': 'false'})
}
function setpermisoread(id,user){
    Drive.Permissions.insert({'role': 'reader','type': 'user','value': user},id,{'sendNotificationEmails': 'false'})
}
function setpermisowrite(id,user){
    Drive.Permissions.insert({'role': 'writer','type': 'user','value': user},id,{'sendNotificationEmails': 'false' })
}

function permissionstotal(){

  var parentFolderId = "parentFolderId";
  var idfilesheet="idfilesheet";
  var useractive = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var jefes = ["EMAIL@EMAIL.COM","EMAIL@EMAIL.COM", "EMAIL@EMAIL.COM","EMAIL@EMAIL.COM"]
  var userviewer="EMAIL@EMAIL.COM"
  
  setpermisosreader(parentFolderId,jefes)
  setpermisosreader(idfilesheet,jefes)
  setpermisoread(idfilesheet,useractive)
  removepermission(parentFolderId,useractive)
  setpermisoread(parentFolderId, useractive)
  //setpermisowrite(idfilesheet,userviewer)
  
  //setpermisoread(parentFolderId,userviewer)
}

function addNewRow(array,obj) {

  var admin ="ADMIN"
  var useractive = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var timestamp = new Date();
  var sheet="DATA"
  var jefes = ["EMAIL@EMAIL.COM","EMAIL@EMAIL.COM", "EMAIL@EMAIL.COM","EMAIL@EMAIL.COM"]
  var userviewer="EMAIL@EMAIL.COM"
  var parentFolderId = "parentFolderId";
  var idfile="idfile"
  var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(parentFolderId);
  setpermisowrite(parentFolderId,useractive)
  setpermisowrite(idfile,useractive)
  var folderName = "SIP "+array.numsip+"/"+array.rut;
  var foldercreated = parentFolder.getFoldersByName(folderName);
  foldercreated = foldercreated.hasNext() ? foldercreated.next() : parentFolder.createFolder(folderName);
  var idfolder= foldercreated.getId()
  appendrow(idfile,sheet,array.numsip,array.rut,timestamp,useractive,idfolder,array.input,array.ticket)
  setownerid(idfolder,admin)
  setpermisosreader(idfolder,jefes)
  //setpermisoread(idfolder,userviewer)
  
  return obj.map(({fileName, mimeType, data}) => {
  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(Utilities.base64Decode(data), mimeType, fileName);
  var foldercode = foldercreated.createFile(blob).getId();
  var archivo = fileExists(foldercode,idfolder);
  if (archivo==false){
    
    console.log("archivo ya existe")
     
  }
  else{

  setpermisosreader(foldercode,jefes)
  //setpermisoread(foldercode,userviewer)
  setownerid(foldercode,admin)
  removepermission(foldercode,useractive)
  setpermisoread(foldercode,useractive)
  removepermission(idfolder,useractive)
  setpermisoread(idfolder,useractive)
  console.log("archivo creado")

 return foldercode
    
  }
  
  });
  
}

function getsip(sipCode){
 //var sipCode= "123"
  var url ="URL SHEET";
  var ss2= SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws2= ss2.getSheetByName("DATA")
  var data2 = ws2.getRange(2, 1, ws2.getLastRow(), 2).getDisplayValues()
  var idList = data2.map(function(r) {return r[0];});
  
  var position = idList.indexOf(sipCode)
  if (position >-1){
    console.log (idList[position])
    return "REPETIDO";
     
  } else{
    console.log ("2")
  return "NOREPETIDO"
    }
}
```

This is the Javascript code:

```
function enviardatosvalidados(){

  var validacion=document.getElementById("sipcode").value

if(validacion=="REPETIDO"){
 
  $('#modal2').modal('hide')
  $('#modalval').modal('show')
  }
else{
  
  try{

enviardatos()
$("#generar").attr("disabled", true)
google.script.run.permissionstotal()
setTimeout(function(){ 
    
  $("#generar").attr("disabled", false)  ; }, 25000)
  window.reloadTheWebApp = function() {
    console.log('reloadTheWebApp ran');

    var linkTag = document.getElementById('testLink');

    linkTag.click();
  }

  }  catch(error){
    alert("Hubo un error.")
    alert(error)

  }
  
}

}
  function enviardatos(){
     if(validate()){

  var sip = document.getElementById("numsip")
  var rut = document.getElementById("rut")
  var input = document.getElementById("input") 
  var ticket = document.getElementById("ticket") 
  var array ={numsip: sip.value,rut: rut.value, input:input.value,ticket:ticket.value}
  const f = document.getElementById('files');

Promise.all([...f.files].map((file, i) => {
  const fr = new FileReader();
  return new Promise((r, rj) => {
    fr.onload = (e) => {
      const data = e.target.result.split(",");
      r({fileName: f.files[i].name, mimeType: data[0].match(/:(\w.+);/)[1], data: data[1]});
    }
    fr.onerror = (e) => rj(e);
    fr.readAsDataURL(file);
  });
}))
.then(obj => google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(console.log).addNewRow(array, obj))
.catch(err => alert(err));
$('#modal2').modal('hide')

successnotification2()
  setTimeout(function(){ 
    
    $(':input').val('');
    
    $("#modalcarpeta").modal('show'); }, 25000);
    ;
  
  }
  else{
    $('#modal2').modal('hide')
    
  }
  }

  function validate(){
  var fieldsToValidate = document.querySelectorAll("#userform input, #userform select");
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(fieldsToValidate, function(el){
  if(el.checkValidity()){
  el.classList.remove("is-invalid");
  
  }else{
  el.classList.add("is-invalid");
     
  }
       
  });
  
  return Array.prototype.every.call(fieldsToValidate, function(el){
  return el.checkValidity();
    
  });
      
   } 

  function checkRut(rut) {
    // Despejar Puntos
    var valor = rut.value.replace('.','');
    // Despejar Guión
    valor = valor.replace('-','');
    
    // Aislar Cuerpo y Dígito Verificador
    cuerpo = valor.slice(0,-1);
    dv = valor.slice(-1).toUpperCase();
    
    // Formatear RUN
    rut.value = cuerpo + '-'+ dv
    
    // Si no cumple con el mínimo ej. (n.nnn.nnn)
    if(cuerpo.length < 7) { rut.setCustomValidity("RUT Incompleto"); return false;}
    
    // Calcular Dígito Verificador
    suma = 0;
    multiplo = 2;
    
    // Para cada dígito del Cuerpo
    for(i=1;i<=cuerpo.length;i++) {
    
        // Obtener su Producto con el Múltiplo Correspondiente
        index = multiplo * valor.charAt(cuerpo.length - i);
        
        // Sumar al Contador General
        suma = suma + index;
        
        // Consolidar Múltiplo dentro del rango [2,7]
        if(multiplo < 7) { multiplo = multiplo + 1; } else { multiplo = 2; }
  
    }
    
    // Calcular Dígito Verificador en base al Módulo 11
    dvEsperado = 11 - (suma % 11);
    
    // Casos Especiales (0 y K)
    dv = (dv == 'K')?10:dv;
    dv = (dv == 0)?11:dv;
    
    // Validar DV
    if(dvEsperado != dv) { rut.setCustomValidity("RUT Inválido"); return false; }
    
    // Validación
    rut.setCustomValidity('');
}
function successnotification2(){
  
  document.getElementById("save-success2").classList.remove("invisible");
  setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById("save-success2").classList.add("invisible")  
    },25000);
       }

  function getSip(){
   
    var sipCode = document.getElementById("numsip").value;
   
   google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updatesipcode).getsip(sipCode);
    
   }
   
   function updatesipcode(sipCode){
   document.getElementById("sipcode").value = sipCode;
   
   
   }

document.getElementById("numsip").addEventListener("input",getSip)
```

Greetings and Thank You!

Comment: Is your folder structure more than two levels?

Comment: it's fairly meaningless to me to debug code that's written in an unfamiliar language.  My guess is that will be a problem for others.  It's hard to get any syntactical connections.  If you're not successful here you might wish to try another forum.

Comment: If your folder structure is deeper than two levels you might wish to try recursion.

Comment: It's only have Two levels for folder: the parent folder and foldercode. The files are in foldercode folder... The foldercode folder Is not duplicated...

Comment: I'd say it's time to learn how to  use the debugger and begin looking for incosistencies.  The fact that you not getting  errors probably just means there nothing wrong with the code it's just not doing what you think it should do.  Probably there's something wrong with your thinking.  It happens to me a lot.  That's why they gave us the debugger.

Comment: Potentially you problem is related to the event listener that might fire more than once and runa function multiple times. For troubleshooting reduce your code to see where exactly the error comes from and also condider implementing e.g. some bollean trat changes it"s values once the function has been ran once to make sure that it does not run a second time.

Comment: @ziganotschka thank you for that observation. I deleted the line but 
my problem keeps happening.

Comment: @Cooper i changed my method and i execute some tests and i didn't have the problem. I will publish my new solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My old method it was very "heavy". When i set the permission to the folder and files, i had to call a lot of times the Driver API and the services. Other problem it was that the parent folder had a lot of folders and many files  which made it take a long time to set the permissions to the user or revocate permissions.
My new method was create a folder with edit permission for the users and move the files and folder to the destiny folder for other users. My objetive was set the correct permissions for final users.This is my new code. The javascript's code doesn't have problems:

```
function moveFiles(sourceFileId, targetFolderId) {
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(sourceFileId);
  file.getParents().next().removeFile(file);
  DriveApp.getFolderById(targetFolderId).addFile(file);
}

function fileExists(idfileexist,folderId) {
var consulta = DriveApp.getFileById(idfileexist).getName()
  var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName(consulta);
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var folders = file.getParents();
    if (folders.hasNext()) {
      var folder = folders.next();
      if (folder.getId() == folderId) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
  
  return false;
}

function removepermission(id, user){
DriveApp.getFileById(id).removeEditor(user)
}
function appendrow(idfile,sheet,numsip,rut,timestamp,user,idfolder,exedoc,ticket){

var values = SpreadsheetApp.openById(idfile);
var ss= values.getSheetByName(sheet);
ss.appendRow([numsip,rut,timestamp,user,idfolder,exedoc,ticket])
}
function setpermisoswriter(id,array){

var file = DriveApp.getFileById(id)
var editors = file.getEditors();
if (editors.length > 0) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    Drive.Permissions.insert({'role': 'writer','type': 'user','value': array[i]},id,{'sendNotificationEmails': 'false' });};};
}
function setpermisosreader(id,array){
var file = DriveApp.getFileById(id)
var editors = file.getEditors();
if (editors.length > 0) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    Drive.Permissions.insert({'role': 'reader','type': 'user','value': array[i]},id,{'sendNotificationEmails': 'false' });};};
}
function setownerid(id,user){
Drive.Permissions.insert({'role': 'owner','type': 'user','value': user},id,{'sendNotificationEmails': 'false'})
}
function setpermisoread(id,user){
    Drive.Permissions.insert({'role': 'reader','type': 'user','value': user},id,{'sendNotificationEmails': 'false'})
}
function setpermisowrite(id,user){
    Drive.Permissions.insert({'role': 'writer','type': 'user','value': user},id,{'sendNotificationEmails': 'false' })
}

function addNewRow(array,obj) {
  var admin ="ADMIN"
  var useractive = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var timestamp = new Date();
  var sheet="DATA"
  var parentFolderIdorigen ="PARENT FOLDER"
  var idfile="IDSHEET"
  var parentFolderorigen = DriveApp.getFolderById(parentFolderIdorigen)
  var parentFolderIddestino = "ID"
  setpermisowrite(idfile,useractive)
  var folderName = "SIP "+array.numsip+"/"+array.rut;
  var foldercreated = parentFolderorigen.getFoldersByName(folderName);
  foldercreated = foldercreated.hasNext() ? foldercreated.next() : parentFolderorigen.createFolder(folderName);
  var idfolder= foldercreated.getId()
  appendrow(idfile,sheet,array.numsip,array.rut,timestamp,useractive,idfolder,array.input,array.ticket)
  setownerid(idfolder,admin)
  return obj.map(({fileName, mimeType, data}) => {
  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(Utilities.base64Decode(data), mimeType, fileName);
  var foldercode = foldercreated.createFile(blob).getId();
  var archivo = fileExists(foldercode,idfolder);
  if (archivo==false){
      
    console.log("archivo ya existe")
     
  }
  else{
    setownerid(foldercode,admin)
    
  moveFiles(idfolder,parentFolderIddestino)
  moveFiles(foldercode,idfolder)
  console.log("archivo creado")
 return foldercode
    
  }
  
  });
  
}

function getsip(sipCode){
 
  var url ="URLSHEET";
  var ss2= SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws2= ss2.getSheetByName("DATA")
  var data2 = ws2.getRange(2, 1, ws2.getLastRow(), 2).getDisplayValues()
  var idList = data2.map(function(r) {return r[0];});
  
  var position = idList.indexOf(sipCode)
  if (position >-1){
    console.log (idList[position])
    return "REPETIDO";
     
  } else{
    console.log ("2")
  return "NOREPETIDO"
    }
}
```

Thanks to @Cooper and @ziganotschka for their comments.